# Crash: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, uitableview, cloudkit

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is my `ViewController` code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


var objects = [Play]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Play", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay= Play()
                newPlay.title = play["Title"] as! String
                newPlay.description = play["Description"] as! String

                NSLog("Title %@", newPlay.title);

                self.objects.append(newPlay)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return objects.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let object = objects[indexPath.row]

    if let label = cell.textLabel{
        label.text = object.title
    }

    return cell
}
```

Everything seems to be hooked up in my Storyboard too.

[image]

Any ideas?  Will post any extra code as needed, thanks!

Comment: Which object comes out to be `nil`?

Comment: Both of them somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pulling the wrong key from CloudKit.  Thanks for the help!